# Having difficulty with PHP forgotten password link

Tags: php

Hi I have a forgotten password script in which when the user clicks the email link and it sends back to the password reset page. Once clicked it goes to the desired page, but there is a problem both send forms come up. I have a forgotten password file as well. If you've seen the picture, that's what is coming up. I am a bit new to PHP. I just want show the new password and confirm new password form.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2qhxovodk3rlrv/2015-07-15_0814.png?dl=0

**The script:**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
    <?php 
require_once 'connection.php';

if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
{
$get_username = $_GET['username'];
$get_code = $_GET['code'];
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE username='$get_username'");

while ($row1s = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
 $db_code= $row1s['passreset'];
 $db_username= $row1s['username'];
}
if ($get_username == $db_username && $get_code == $db_code ) 
{
    echo "

    <form action='forgotpassword_process.php' method='post'>

            <legend><h1 style='color:red;'>Forgot Password</h1></legend><br>

            <div class='input-field col s6'>

                <div class='form-group'>

                    <span class='help-block'>Enter Your New Password</span>

                    <input type='password' name='newpass' class='form-control' placeholder='New Password '>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class='input-field col s6'>

                <div class='form-group'>

                    <span class='help-block'>Re-Enter Your Password  </span><br>

                    <input type='password' name='password1' class='form-control' placeholder='Password'>

                </div>

            </div>


            <input type='submit' name='submit' class='btn' value='Update Password' />
            <input type='hidden' name='username' class='btn' value='$db_username' />


        </form>




    ";
    }


}


?>


    <form action="forgotpassword_process.php" method="post">

            <legend><h1 style="color:red;">Forgot Password</h1></legend><br>

            <div class="input-field col s6">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <span class="help-block">Enter your username</span>

                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <span class="help-block">Enter your email </span><br>

                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">

                </div>

            </div>


            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="submit" />


        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: from your script you have 2 forms showing the same thing. remove one.

Comment: but if i remove the upper form the password reset form will not work

Comment: remove the lower one.

Comment: if i remove the lower one that form send the actual pasword rest email for the URL

Comment: the code for the form process  https://www.dropbox.com/s/61mx1kgcanrouni/2015-07-15_0855.png?dl=0

Comment: In `forgotpassword_process.php`, vars : `newpass` and `password1` seems unused, it's normal ?

Answer (score 0):

before the second form you can add an `else` condition, like this

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
    <?php 
require_once 'connection.php';

if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
{
  $get_username = $_GET['username'];
  $get_code = $_GET['code'];
  $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE username='$get_username'");

while ($row1s = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
 $db_code= $row1s['passreset'];
 $db_username= $row1s['username'];
}
if ($get_username == $db_username && $get_code == $db_code ) 
{
    echo "

    <form action='forgotpassword_process.php' method='post'>

            <legend><h1 style='color:red;'>Forgot Password</h1></legend><br>

            <div class='input-field col s6'>

                <div class='form-group'>

                    <span class='help-block'>Enter Your New Password</span>

                    <input type='password' name='newpass' class='form-control' placeholder='New Password '>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class='input-field col s6'>

                <div class='form-group'>

                    <span class='help-block'>Re-Enter Your Password  </span><br>

                    <input type='password' name='password1' class='form-control' placeholder='Password'>

                </div>

            </div>


            <input type='submit' name='submit' class='btn' value='Update Password' />
            <input type='hidden' name='username' class='btn' value='$db_username' />
        </form>
    ";
    }
} else {
?>
    <form action="forgotpassword_process.php" method="post">

            <legend><h1 style="color:red;">Forgot Password</h1></legend><br>

            <div class="input-field col s6">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <span class="help-block">Enter your username</span>

                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <span class="help-block">Enter your email </span><br>

                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">

                </div>

            </div>


            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="submit" />


        </form>

    </div>

</div>
<?php 
  } // end else 
?>
```